# Connecting iSCSI target to my vSphere client

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware, virtualization, esxi, iscsi

I have used the new Microsoft iSCSI software target 3.3 and manage to attach a virtual disk and create an iSCSI target initiator. Now when I try to add this under the iSCSI software adapter in vSphere client and after scanning the HBA it shows no devices what so ever. I have tried Starwind management console, iSCSI cake and many more and has not been able to find out. Please help me me as I'm trying to simulate a lab environment for vcp.

What I am using

Windows server 2008 r2
Esxi 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Replace your target with StarWind. Just make sure you've CREATED device BEFORE you're connecting to.

-nismo